# How to define a return List<T> for a LinqToSql Join?

Tags: linq-to-sql, join

I use Linq To Sql Join Query in DAL layer, How can I define a return `List<T>` automatically for the LinqToSql Join method?

Nowadays, I have to manually define a `List<CustomViewType>` for each LinqToSql Join method's return value.

Is that possible to define a `List<T>` like the following code :

```
public static List<T> GetJoinList()
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();

    list =  from c in customers
            join o in orders on o.customerid equals c.customerid
            select new { CustomerID = c.CustomerId, OrderDate = o.OrderDate } ;

    return list.ToList() ;
}
```

In fact, what I mean is that how can I pass the lists of anonymous types from DAL layer to BLL layer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must still create a custom class for the return type since you can't return anonymous classes from methods. You can avoid declaring and assigning the list though using the `ToList()` extension method:

```
public static List<CustomViewType> GetJoinList()
{
    return (from c in customers
            join o in orders on o.customerid equals c.customerid
            select new CustomViewType { CustomerID = c.CustomerId, OrderDate = o.OrderDate}).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Well, you *can* return lists of anonymous types... you just can't do so in a strongly typed way.

Comment: Then how to pass the lists of anonymous types from DAL layer to BLL layer?